# Recursively iterate over nested structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have nested folder objects like a directory structure on a file system. A user could have:

- Folder 1
- Folder 2

  - Folder 2a
  - Folder 2b

    - Folder 2ba
    - Folder 2bb
- Folder 3

and so on, as far down as the user wants. I am trying to display the folder structure as in above in a view.

I could do `each` on the first level, and for each folder in that level, do `each` on it's children, and then `each` on it's children and so on, manually. But that seems inefficient. I don't want there to be a pre-set limit to the levels. This seems something that should be automated, but I'm not quite sure how to do so. Furthermore, it seems recursion is not an option because there are no methods in a view.

Is this something a helper would be good for? Should I give up and only load a subfolder when the parent folder is clicked on, using javascript?

Comment: You may want to look at the `awesome_nested_set` or `ancestry` gems. No sense in reinventing the wheel!

Comment: There's anything you want in a view, including rendering the same view (think partial) from within itself. What's `render` if not a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming you have a `Folder` class with a `subfolders` method, you'll want to have a recursive partial, say `_folder.html.erb`:

```
<li><%= folder.name %></li>
<% unless folder.subfolders.empty? -%>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <%= render partial: "folder", collection: folder.subfolders %>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% end -%>
```

Then set some padding on your `ul`s and you should be good to go.

The initial call to the partial would probably look something like this where `@folders` contains your top level folders and would live in a `folders.html.erb` or similar:

```
<ul>
  <%= render partial: "folder", collection: @folders %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.add_in_children(folder)

    folder.children.each do |child|

      @all_folders << [level,child]
      @level+=1
      if child.children
        add_in_children(child)
      end
    end
  end 

  def self.all_records
    @all_folders=[]
    @level=0
    @folders=add_in_children('/')
  end

end

Folder.all_records;
```